# How to build a post request to verify PayPal webhook signature in python?

Tags: python, paypal

I need to verify the the signature of the PayPal webhooks I receive.
(The PayPal-Python-SDK is not an option since it is deprecated)

Here is what I'm trying:

```
access_token = "Bearer " + r['access_token']

data = {"auth_algo": auth_algo,
        "transmission_id": transmission_id,
        "transmission_sig": transmission_sig,
        "transmission_time": transmission_time,
        "webhook_id": webhookID,
        "webhook_event": res,
        "cert_url":cert_url }

headers = {"Authorization":access_token, "Content-Type": "application/json"}


response = requests.post("https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/notifications/verify-webhook-signature", data=data, headers=headers)
```

Getting a 400 response:

> {'name': 'VALIDATION_ERROR', 'message': 'Invalid request - see details', 'debug_id': '4d3f231bb0c69', 'details': [{'location': 'body', 'issue': 'MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON'}], 'links': []}

- I'm not sure if the access token should go in the headers.
- Also not sure if the url is the correct one but please note that I'm
  testing this in production and not in sandbox.
- Also unsure if there should be a "Bearer" prefix on the
  token.

I'm trying to follow this guide:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/v1/#verify-webhook-signature_post

Answer (score 1):

> data=data

data takes a string, not a python dict

You need to use `json=` , https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: thank you: I seem to have an error in the webhook_event field ::: {'name': 'VALIDATION_ERROR', 'message': 'Invalid request - see details', 'debug_id': '4d3f231bb0c69', 'details': [{'location': 'body', 'issue': 'MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON'}], 'links': []}.

Comment: I am using the raw json webhook I receive from paypal as the webhook_event field in the signature validation call. Also I have been careful to use the access token for production.

Comment: data= takes a string, you need to use json=

Comment: it worked! thank you a lot Preston. One more question, is it a bad practice to get an access token everytime I receive a webhook? I'm trying to avoid having to renew the token every month or so.

Comment: Tokens are cached (you'll get the same one if you repeat the call) and expire after 9 hours usually, there is an `expires_in` in the response. Cache them yourself rather than repeating the call, as you like.